# What would be the benefit of binding result of operation to it self after mem_swap with empty one

Tags: rust, swap

I've been going through the base code of some Rust library (Carboxyl) and found some weird code. It performs a filter map to a Vector after swapping it with an empty one and reassigning the result to the original identifier.

```
impl<A: Send + Sync + Clone + 'static> Source<A> {
    /// Make the source send an event to all its observers.
    pub fn send(&mut self, a: A) {
        use std::mem;
        let mut new_callbacks = vec!();
        mem::swap(&mut new_callbacks, &mut self.callbacks);
        self.callbacks = new_callbacks
            .into_iter()
            .filter_map(|mut callback| {
                let result = callback(a.clone());
                match result {
                    Ok(_) => Some(callback),
                    Err(_) => None,
                }
            })
            .collect();
    }
}
```

What would be the possible benefits of doing so compared to performing filter_map to the original identifier and reassigning the result to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is that it's possible.
Because `callbacks` is part of `self` which is behind a mutable reference you can't move out of it with `into_iter()`.

Once [`drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter) stabilizes this can be done inplace but until then this is the solution.